# How to catch java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString Exception in Controller?

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

I have a checkbox in my JSP page that accepts integer values:

```
<form:checkbox path="somePath" value="2" /> Dangerous Checkbox <br />
```

If the user changes the value of the input to a `String` value, e.g.:

```
<form:checkbox path="somePath" value="blah" /> Dangerous Checkbox <br />
```

the page will throw a `NumberFormatException`. How can I catch this in my Controller and show a meaningful message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use JSTL's [**c:catch**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/catch.html) tag:

```
<c:catch var ="numberFormatException">
<form:checkbox path="somePath" value="blah" /> Dangerous Checkbox <br />
</c:catch>

<c:if test = "${numberFormatException!= null}">
   <p>The exception is : ${numberFormatException} <br />
   There is an exception: ${numberFormatException.message}</p>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Awesome! I browsed for so long and nothing turned up. Stackoverflow surpasses google :D Thanks.

Comment: Btw, is there any way I can feed this into the `BindingResult` variable?